# How can I use color output in a tmux run-shell command?

Tags: tmux, colors

I've bound a key to run a script with tmux's `run-shell` command, but I can't find any way to use color output.

- normal ansi codes do not work, e.g.
  `echo -e "\e[32mblah blah\e[0m"`
- tmux formatting does not work (nor did I expect it to), e.g.
  `echo -e "#[fg=colour250]blah blah"`
- nor has anything else I've tried, like 256-color codes, e.g.
  `printf "\x1b[38;5;57mblah blah"`

Comment: if you can track it through `tmux`, then just write to its pty, or else, before you open `tmux`, export a variable like `TMUX_PTY=$(tty) tmux ...` and later write to that when you want it.

Answer (score 1):

There is no workaround for `run-shell`, because `tmux` copies the data from the job in [`screen_write_vnputs`](https://github.com/tmux/tmux/blob/master/screen-write.c#L267), discarding any escape characters (as well as most other control characters).  Here's the relevant chunk of code:

```
        if (*ptr == '\001')
            gc.attr ^= GRID_ATTR_CHARSET;
        else if (*ptr > 0x1f && *ptr < 0x7f) {
            size++;
            screen_write_putc(ctx, &gc, *ptr);
        }
        ptr++;
```